# RECORD_SOUND_ACTION intent, go straight to recordings list

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that fires the intent for the voice recorder (RECORD_SOUND_ACTION), but I want it to go straight to the listing of recordings. Is there a putExtra I can add to get this result?

Comment: Are you trying to select an existing recording to be passed back to your `Activity`?

Comment: Noper. I'm just trying to start the Voice Recorder app and go straight to the list of recordings.

Comment: I'm not aware of an Android "listing of recordings".  Could you clarify?  Do you mean that you want to build up your own `ListView`?  Or did you mean that you just want the file, if any, that the user just recorded after your intent call?

Comment: No. At the moment, I'm just firing an intent that start the Voice Recorder. When it starts, it shows it's main activity page. I'm hoping that there's a way to add a putExtra to the Intent so that it start Voice Recorder on it's List View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an HTC phone--I believe Voice Recorder is a stock HTC app, not an Android standard app.  If that's the case, if you can find the apk, you might be able to reverse engineer an intent using [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&hl=en)--though this would only work for people that have HTC devices and/or a compatible version of Voice Recorder.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Alternately, you could without too much effort call `ACTION_PICK` and subsequently launch an audio player on the returned file.  To [call an audio file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461112/403455):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
   android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Gallery"), reqCode);
```

Or alternately,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), reqCode);
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't resolve it. Using AppXplore and, later, dex2jar and  jd-gui, I managed to try every Activity and a few direct class calls in com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder, but to no avail. Good learning experience though. TY.