# Android: open dialog for select audio

Tags: android, audio, select, android-intent

I need to allow user to select some audiofile from his media library.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
        Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(
              Intent.ACTION_PICK,
              android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
              );

        startActivityForResult(tmpIntent, 0);
```

But I get error:

```
08-20 17:44:35.444: E/AndroidRuntime(3773): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/audio/media }
```

To be on the safe side, I also tried `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, but result is similar.

How can I achieve this?

**UPD:** by the way, if I try to pass URI to get images (i.e. `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`), then it works: image open dialog is opened.

**UPD2:** Just tried this on emulator - my code works! But on two devices it doesn't (SE Xperia Neo and some Acer). But if I try the second variant from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461065/how-to-pickup-an-audio-files-path-or-uri-from-device-in-android/10461112#10461112), then I got menu with all my existing file-managers, and with "Music select" too! But I need to write Intent just to open this "Music select".

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10461112/582571

Comment: thank you, it brought some light, but still no luck on my device. I updated my question, check it please.

Comment: first variant also work in my LG mobile.

Comment: But on my SE mobile first variant shows empty dialog with the note: "no application can perform this action". But anyway I solved this problem, you can check out my own answer on this question. Thanks again for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have seen in LogCat what happens when I open music select dialog, and I got what I need. This code works for me:

```
     Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
     startActivityForResult(tmpIntent, 0);
```

If I want to get, say, notifications sounds only, then I need to put extra, just like that:

```
     Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
     tmpIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     startActivityForResult(tmpIntent, 0);
```

Comment: how to get the file path of music path from that activity in OnactivityResult

Comment: but that sample code doesn't show music dialog, it shows a ringtones dialog.