# Play notification audio by URI

Tags: android

I have URI of the notification sound, like `content://media/internal/audio/media/122`, but `SoundPool` doesn't work with URIs, it works with only apk resources of file paths.

Is there a way to get media file path from URI? I tried `Uri.getPath()`, which returns `/internal/audio/media/122`, but this isn't valid file path, and of course `SoundPool` doesn't work with such patch.

Actually the real path to the notification is `/system/media/audio/notifications/allegro.ogg` , and I see no way to get it from URI like `content://media/internal/audio/media/122`

Or should I use `MediaPlayer` for that? I tested, it works:

```
           MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, "content://media/internal/audio/media/122");
           mp.start();
```

I'm confused because `MediaPlayer` seems to be too heavy to just play short notification sound, so I'd prefer to use `SoundPool`.

Please tell me if I'm wrong about `MediaPlayer` weight, and suggest correct way to play notification sound by its URI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913427/how-to-get-the-uri-from-mediastore-via-file-path

Comment: Thank you, this brought some light and I solved the problem. Check out my own answer to this question if you are interested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I got the easiest way to play audio by URI:

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/122")).play();
```

I think this is the best what i could achieve.

Comment: The downside is that Ringtone uses MediaPlayer internally, yet does not provide an easy way to release it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a full path:

```
String path = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); //Will return "/system"
path = path + Uri.getPath().subString(9); //To cut "content:/" from the Uri path.
//Then pass this "path" to your SoundPool
```

You are right. Unlike MediaPlayer which is used for music and videos, SoundPool is meant to be used for *short app audio resources* like notifications. It is much faster and lighter than MediaPlayer.

Comment: Thanks, and suggest please, should I use MediaPlayer instead, if "SoundPool is meant to be used for short app audio resources"?

Comment: @DmitryFrank Updated. If your sound is short then stick to the SoundPool. If it is long and the SoundPool didn't work well, then you need to switch to the MediaPlayer. That's what I would do.

Comment: Unfortunately your way does not work: the real path to the notification is `/system/media/audio/notifications/allegro.ogg` , and I see no way to get it from URI like `content://media/internal/audio/media/122`.

Comment: Why are you using Uri? You could provide the `notification path` as a String using [`sp.load()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I use URI because I get URI from media select dialog. See this answer to get what dialog I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038946/android-open-dialog-for-select-audio/12048448#12048448

Comment: it seems like you didn't read carefully my comments. Uri.getPath() returns `/internal/audio/media/122`, but the real path to the file is `/system/media/audio/notifications/allegro.ogg`.  Could you please feel the difference? They are completely different, there's not just `/system` at the beginning.

Comment: Yes it can, but it needs for file path, i.e. `/system/media/audio/notifications/allegro.ogg`, not `content://media/internal/audio/media/122`.

Comment: Sorry. I thought `/system/media/internal/audio/media/122` will work. You may want to try the first method in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603837/543711). Sounds promising.

Comment: Anyway, problem seems to be solved now (check out my own answer to this question). Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Dmitry's answer.

One line can solved the problem.

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)).play();
```