# Android SoundPool how to load Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI

Tags: android, soundpool

i'm trying to load the phone default notification sound into my SoundPool.

i've tried

`soundPool.load(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.getPath(), 1)`

and got

```
11-19 20:57:39.770: E/SoundPool(2948): error loading /system/notification_sound
```

how can i load it ?

Comment: please share full logcat logs...

Comment: but this is the logcat regarding the SoundPool. BTW, other sounds from file it loads perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12050562/1092770) thread.

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/122")).play();
```

Comment: That shows how to play it using the Ringtone class (which uses MediaPlayer internally).  It would still be good to know how to load it into a SoundPool.