# How do get a URI from a ListView item with onclick?

Tags: java, android, uri

Hi everybody fairly new to java and android development, I need help to get the URI from the item that the user clicks on so that it can be played.

This is all the code I have thus far please help for I have been stuck at this specific problem for some time now.

the problem is in the onItemClickListner.

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.i("Permission ","gRANTED");
            }
        }
    }
    ListView musicListView;
    ArrayList<String> musicArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Uri songUri;

    public void play(View view){

    }
    public void pause(View view){

    }
    public void stop(View view){

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }catch (Exception e){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        }
        musicListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.musicListView);
        musicArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, musicArrayList);
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME };// Can include more data for more details and check it.

        Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

        if(audioCursor != null){
            if(audioCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    int audioIndex = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    musicArrayList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioIndex));
                }while(audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        audioCursor.close();

        musicListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        musicListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                songUri =//////PLEASE HELP ME GET THIS//////; 
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                        new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                                .build()
                );
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add model class and adapter class? So it may help to get the answer.

Comment: Hi Ramesh tI just updated all the code

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet tried this solution but in general the way pointed in this answer can solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461112/3400640

Comment: thank you, but I'm still having trouble... let me ask this instead how can i log out the URI of the selected item?